# Install programs files to separate disk to OS

Tags: filesystems, partition, crunchbang

I am going to install BunsenLabs Crunchbang on my laptop that has 250gb SSD and a 1tb HDD. I am coming from a Windows 8/10 background so I am not familiar with the way the file system works.

I want to have my OS files on the SSD with the majority of my programs installed on the HHD. Yet I would like some programs installed on the SSD. How would I set the drives up to achieve this? Do I need to partition the disks on install or is it easier to change each program's install directory individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install software using package managers such as RPM (in Fedora and Redhat) and APT (in Debian and Ubuntu), the applications usually will be installed in folders such as `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` and `/opt`. Tipically, software that is not part of the operating system will reside in `/opt`.

To use a different disk for the applications, you may (1) mount the other disk as `/opt` or a sub directory of `/opt`, or (2) create a symbolic link that redirect the folder `/opt` or one of its sub directories to a folder in the other disk.

I prefer the second option. Suppose that you have the other disk in `/mnt/otherdisk`, you can create a folder before installing the software. Note that you must configure the file permissions properly. For instance, if the software will be installed in `/opt/software`

```
mkdir /mnt/otherdisk/opt/software 
ln -s /mnt/otherdisk/opt/software /opt/software
# then install the software
```

If you have installed the software, you can move the files and create the link too. Suppose that the software is installed in `/some/dir` and the other disk is in `/mnt/otherdisk`:

```
mv /some/dir /mnt/otherdisk/some/dir 
ln -s /mnt/otherdisk/some/dir /some/dir
```

Comment: With the symbolic link, how would I have a few applications on the SSD? From the commands, it looks like all the applications are on the HDD...

Comment: When you use typical commands such as `ls /opt`, the listings will show the files in the other disks as if they are in just one. Remember that the Linux/Unix filesystem is a "big tree" without  a letter for each drive. -- to know what is installed in the SSD, you may list that mount point, i.e. `ls /mnt/otherdisk`